# Trying to add selector and not working with me

Tags: jquery

I don't know why the .on ('click') code is not working with the selector
this code is not working whatever I change the selector

```
 $(function () {
    $('.todolist input').on('keydown', function(e){
       if(e.keyCode == 13){
           $('<li>' + $(this).val() + '<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>').appendTo($('.todolist ul'))
           $(this).val('');
       }
    })
})

$(function () {
    $('.todolist .fa-times').on('click', 'li i', function() {
        $(this).parent('li').css('text-decoration', 'line-through').delay(200).fadeOut(300, function () {
        $(this).parent('li').remove();
        });

    });
});
```

This code is working fine without the selector

```
 $(function () {
    $('.todolist .fa-times').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent('li').css('text-decoration', 'line-through').delay(200).fadeOut(300, function () {
        $(this).parent('li').remove();
        });

    });
});
```

I'm making a to-do list and I want after any `<li>` created with jQuery when I click on the icon (x) remove it

```
<div class="container">
<div class="todolist">
    <h3>To Do List:</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Learning JQuery<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Codeing My 1st Site<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Learning Angular js<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Learning SAS<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>More Training<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Task">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your delegated event handler has both selector and delegation:

```
$('.todolist .fa-times').on('click', 'li i', function() {
```

`li i` is not a sub-node of `.fa-times` (ie `$(".todolist .fa-times li i").length === 0)`)

change to

```
$('.todolist').on('click', 'li i.fa-times', function() {
```

or just:

```
$('.todolist').on('click', '.fa-times', function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove space in selector:

```
$(function () {
$('.todolist.fa-times').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent('li').css('text-decoration', 'line-through').delay(200).fadeOut(300, function () {
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
    });

});
});
```

**EDIT:**

`$(element).on('click',...)` event binding works only if you are selecting already existing element. This problem can be solved in various ways, you can either rebind events after creating element, delegate event from parent or bind them directly to `document`.

Example:

```
$(document).on("click", ".todolist.fa-times", function() {
    $(this).parent('li')
         .css('text-decoration', 'line-through')
         .delay(200).fadeOut(300, function () {
             $(this).parent('li').remove();
         });
 });
```

Comment: Can you show us html elements you are trying to select? Are you creating them dynamically?

Comment: @freedomn-m you are right, and answer you provided here is correct solution, which is why I gave your answer +1